# How to find whether index is in RAM or Disk [MongoDB]?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

What is best way to find whether an index in reside in RAM or Disk in mongodb?

Answer (score 5):

On one hand, it is entirely possible only some parts of the index is in RAM http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexing-right-handed

> Indexes do not have to fit entirely into RAM in all cases. If the value of the indexed field grows with every insert, and most queries select recently added documents; then MongoDB only needs to keep the parts of the index that hold the most recent or “right-most” values in RAM. This allows for efficient index use for read and write operations and minimize the amount of RAM required to support the index.

On the other hand, `db.serverStatus()` gives you an aggregate of the information you wanted. Check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#server-status-indexcounters:

> The `indexCounters.btree.hits` value reflects the number of times that an index has been accessed and mongod is able to return the index from memory.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `db.serverStatus().indexCounters.btree` But It shows an object with all zeros.

` {
  "accesses" : 0,
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0,
  "resets" : 0,
  "missRatio" : 0
 }`
I ran query few times and my query uses an index. explain() shows it.
Can you find why?

Comment: What version are you running? The docs indicate that "In 2.2 and later, these data reflect actual index use."

Comment: Hi, It's not possible anymore like this as of MongoDB 3.0+ `Changed in version 3.0: The server status output no longer includes the workingSet, indexCounters, and recordStats sections.` https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#server-status-output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You can use `totalIndexSize()` or  `stats()`  to check the size of the index

```
> db.collection.totalIndexSize()
> 1073741824


> db.collection.stats()
> {
"ns" : "collection.test",
"count" : 100006,
"size" : 72104,
"avgObjSize" : 4506.5,
"storageSize" : 688128,
"numExtents" : 3,
"nindexes" : 1,
"lastExtentSize" : 524288,
"paddingFactor" : 1.0170000000000319,
"systemFlags" : 1,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 1073741824,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 1073741824
},
"ok" : 1
```

Both will return the index size of the collection in bytes. Above example shows the index size is `1GB`.

**UPDATE**

To find the total index size of the entire database, you can use `stats()`

```
 > db.stats()
{
    "db" : "test",
    "collections" : 10,
    "objects" : 5909990,
    "avgObjSize" : 2888.31186440677965,
    "dataSize" : 170123304,
    "storageSize" : 14745603499,
    "numExtents" : 17,
    "indexes" : 8,
    "indexSize" : 1073741824,
    "fileSize" : 50331648,
    "nsSizeMB" : 163453,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now you can compare `indexSize` with the machine RAM to check whether the index fits in memory or not. And you can increase the RAM size to accommodate the full index.

Hope it helps

Comment: But that doesn't say anything about where the index is...?

Comment: @RameshVel I have enough RAM but I was looking for a direct solution whether I can look for it.